# Django: login_redirect_url not working

Tags: python, django

I have written my own login and logout views.

I am using `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to set the redirect page.

My login view is fairly simple:

```
def todologin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            url = reverse('pilot:home')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def home(request):
```

I am using `@login_required` on my homepage.

This is the value of the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
# tried this one too, LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'pilot:login'
```

My app's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/', views.signup),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login/', views.todologin, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.todologout, name='logout'),
]
```

Still, it always redirects to `/accounts/login/?next=/home/`

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have to check if `authenticate` returned `None`.

Comment: yeah valid point, I was going to do that later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override `LOGIN_URL` in `settings.py` like below.

```
# ....
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
# ....
```

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is used by django to redirect the user after successful login.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL

Comment: `[23/Jan/2018 12:59:04] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0`
`Not Found: /accounts/login/`
`[23/Jan/2018 12:59:04] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/home/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2650`

I have used that exact syntax, but it doesn't redirects.

Comment: @Luv33preet It might be the issue of cache. Try to restart the dev server and open browser in incognito mode then access it.